# How to put links on a website in horizontal sequence?

Tags: html, hyperlink

I am new in web designing field and now i and trying to make a clone of a website in HTML, but here is a issue that i want to put link on the top of the website in horizontal sequence. Some body please tell me how to make link in sequence? for example how can i make these links in sequence?

```
<a href="http://poempunch.com/" title="Poems |Poets |Best Poems |Short Poems |Poems Collection - Poempunch.com">Home</a>
```

Comment: I didn't get. You're refering the top menu "Home - Poets - Forum..." ??

Answer (score 2):

Check this layout: http://jsfiddle.net/KFbth/1/

```
<ul id="menu">
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
</ul>
```

and with image from the site you refer: http://jsfiddle.net/KFbth/9/

Answer (score 0):

Very easy... don't put a `<br>` between them and don't make them styled as blocks.

```
<a href="#">Link 1</a>
<a href="#">Link 2</a>
<a href="#">Link 3</a>
```

They can even be on separate lines in the HTML.

**EDIT**

You asked to put images in the links...

```
<a href="#"><img src="link-to-image.jpg" alt="Alt text" /></a>
<a href="#"><img src="link-to-image.jpg" alt="Alt text" /></a>
<a href="#"><img src="link-to-image.jpg" alt="Alt text" /></a>
```

You may also want to put it in a list, since that is "semantically better" if it's navigation.

```
<ul class="navigation">
    <li><a href="#"><img src="link-to-image.jpg" alt="Alt text" /></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><img src="link-to-image.jpg" alt="Alt text" /></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><img src="link-to-image.jpg" alt="Alt text" /></a></li>
</ul>
```

Then you can style this list however you like with css.

```
 <style type="text/css">
     .navigation{list-style-type: none;}
     .navigation li{float:left}
 </style>
```

Comment: hmm  nice thnx,, and plz tell me how to put image in links? i wanna put images in links, like home image on home link and free sms image on free sms link,, thnx

Answer (score 0):

Anchor tags are by default "inline" elements.  If you have changed the default in your CSS file(s), then you may need to style them as inline.  You can test this theory by either evaluating the elements in something like Firebug or adding a style like this:

```
a.inlined {
    display: inline;
}
```

And the links like this:

<a href="home.html" class="inlined">Home</a> 
<a href="other.html" class="inlined" >Other</a>

A better way, is to make sure you don't change the defaults in the first place so that they become unpredictable.

Comment: a.inlined {
    display: inline;
}                        Is this HTML?,, Whats This Code?

Comment: It's CSS code and should go in <style type="text/css"> </style>  If you don't know what CSS is, then you should invest some time learning it because the problem you are having is related to CSS most likely. Here's a CSS tutorial. [Click Here](http://www.w3schools.com/css/default.asp)